# I've tried three npm packages for converting HTML to images and none capture the images on my page, what could be the problem?

Tags: html, reactjs, npm

I've tried [html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image), [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), and [use-react-screenshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-react-screenshot). They all work pretty much the same, they provide a function e.g. html2canvas(element) and you just plug your chosen document element in there.

I've tried so many test configurations now, and I can get it to capture everything else on my page - headers, text, css background images, input boxes, buttons - but *not images*. I've tried capturing a specific div. I've tried capturing the whole body. They all work, except nothing inside an `<img>` tag will appear in the generated image. I even tested it on some random static images in case my dynamically rendered images were the issue, but no, it just won't capture *any* image.

Tearing my hair out! What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that for html2canvas, at least, you have to set a property "allow taint" to "true" or it won't capture any images due to cross-origin images tainting the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `CORS` in the `html2canvas` configuration like so:

```js
html2canvas(document.body, {
    useCORS:true
}).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

[With `useCORS` enabled](https://jsfiddle.net/n9820es6/)

[With*out* `useCORS` enabled](https://jsfiddle.net/s0a1qw4f/)